# View all Firebase Cloud Function's Last Invocations (to prevent inactive functions)

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions

So according to the Google Cloud docs:

> Max inactivity time for background functions = 30 days
>
> The maximum amount of time that a background function can be kept without any invocation. Functions that are not invoked even once during this time may enter a state in which new events will not trigger them anymore. If this happens, such functions have to be redeployed to start working again. Note: This inactive state is not reflected in the UI, CLI, or API in any way.

I have an application with close to 40 cloud functions and there doesn't seem to be an easy way for me to tell if a function is close to becoming inactive so I know to take action before it happens and I really don't want to filter through the logs in the console with each function every week to see when each was invoked last.

Outside of just doing a redeploy of my functions every month to insure they are fresh is there anyway to easily tell when a function is becoming stale in case it does happen so I only have to deploy said function before it becomes stale?

Also, for any firebase'r that might read this, is there any solutions possibly coming to this in the future?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry, there's no way to tell where your function is during its 30 day idle expiration.  The good news is that the Cloud Functions team is working on removing this limitation, but there's no public timeline for that.

**EDIT**: This problem is resolved now for all newly deployed functions.

Comment: Thanks Doug. I had this weird feeling you were going to be the one to see this and respond. :-). Glad to hear this limitation is going to be removed at some point. Cheers.

Comment: It occurs to me that you could write the current timestamp to your database with every function invocation, then you could do some math to figure out how far in the past that was.  But you would obviously reset the timer on your new deploy, and there might be some costs associated with that database write.

Comment: Curious as it's been a year since this post if there are any updates regarding this. Thanks.

Comment: @askilondz This issue is fixed. You have to redeploy your function to apply the fix.